# Thickbox won't submit in IE8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, form-submit, thickbox

I have a Thickbox on a page, using the inline method, that contains a form. I can't get it to submit in IE8. When I click the submit button, it's supposed to send an email and close itself, but nothing happens - the Thickbox remains on the page and I receive no email. It all works fine in Firefox and even IE7.

```
<p><a href="#TB_inline?height=300&width=400&inlineId=AddModeratorsBox&modal=true" class="thickbox" style="text-decoration:none">Add moderators</span></a></p>

<div id="AddModeratorsBox" class="hidden">      
    <p>Add moderators:</p>
    <form name="invitemoderators" action="http://www.mydomain.com/sendEmail.php" method="post">
        <p class="subtleText">Email addresses</p>
        <textarea cols="30" rows="5" name="emails" class="textareabox"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" value="Invite Moderators" class="button" />                
</form>     
</div>
```

I verified that this is the only form on the page. Also, for the action, I tried with relative and full URL, with no luck either way. Does anyone know of any other IE8 quirks that could be causing this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The code for the form looks fine thus I suspect some issue with the thickbox JavaScript you have.  Can you post the code that closes the thickbox after the form submission?

That said, is the HTML above "pre" rendered on the page or are you building it up on the fly in JavaScript?